# How can I call PHP from dayClick?

Tags: php, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I need to save a date in my database through fullcalendar dayclick function, because I'm working with days and not with events.

I have my marcarsenhas.php where I display the calendar and my insert.php where I program the Insert.

I have a Select example that is working so I will provide you everything.

marcarsenhas.php (Where I display the calendar / Showing only the script)

```
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var day;


      var iduser = $("#iduser").attr("valor");
      //alert($("#iduser").attr("valor"));

      //funcionar
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
        selectable: true,
        editable: false,
        events: {                
                url: 'getdados.php',
                 data: {iduser : iduser},
                //data: {d : dia, m : mes, a: ano, id : iduser},
                success: function(){
                   // alert("ok");
                    /*var data_array = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#response").empty().append( data );
                    $("#id_oc").empty().append( data_array['idoc'] );
                    $("#design").empty().append( data_array['design'] );
                    $("#qtd").empty().append( data_array['qtd'] );
                    //$("#box_detail").html(data_array["design"]);*/
                }
          },

          dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 

            //alert(date.format());
            var d = new Date(date._d);

            var dia = d.getDate();
            var mes = d.getMonth()+1;
            var ano = d.getFullYear();

          day=$(this).closest('.'+(view.type=='month'?'fc-row':'fc-time-grid')).find('.fc-bg td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').data('date');
         // if (checkDay.dia() == 6 || checkDay.dia() == 0) alert('Weekend!');
              console.log(day);
              //alert(day);

          $(this).css('background-color', 'green');


              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'insert.php',
                  data: {dia : dia, mes : mes, ano : ano, iduser : iduser},
                  success: function(data){
                      alert(data);
                  }
              });

        }, //end dayclick

      });
  });
```

insert.php

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');

    $dia = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dia']);
    $mes = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mes']);
    $ano = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ano']);
    $iduser = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['iduser']);


    if(empty($_POST['dia']) || empty($_POST['mes']) || empty($_POST['ano']) || empty($_POST['iduser'])){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro!');</script>";


    exit();
  }

      if(isset($_POST['dayClick'])) { // I know that this doesn't work, it's only to guide you

             if(!empty($_POST['dia']) || !empty($_POST['mes']) || !empty($_POST['ano']) || !empty($_POST['iduser'])){
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `t_marcacoes` (dia, mes, ano, iduser) VALUES ('$dia','$mes','$ano','$iduser')";
                    $successok = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                 }

        }

       header('Location:marcarsenhas.php');
?>
```

getdados.php (The php file where I do the Select)

```
<?php
    //echo "entrei";
    require_once('connection.php');



    $dados = array();
    $_POST["iduser"] = 5;
    if(isset($_POST["iduser"]) ){
        $iduser = $_POST["iduser"];


        $query = "SELECT id, iduser, dia, mes, ano, ismarcado FROM t_marcacoes WHERE iduser = ".$iduser;

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);    
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               $dia=$row['dia'];
               $mes=$row['mes'];
               $ano=$row['ano'];

                $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ano.'-'.$mes.'-'.$dia));

                $temp = array(
                    'start' => $date,
                    'end' => $date,
                    'overlap' => true,
                    'rendering' => 'background',
                    'color' => '#15a515',
                    'editable' => false
                );
            array_push($dados, $temp);

        }

    }
echo json_encode($dados);

?>
```

Comment: if you want to send some data to the server following the dayClick event, then inside the "dayClick" function, you need to make an AJAX request. It looks, from your code, like you are already doing that. So presumably you've got some sort of problem with it? What exactly is the problem? You showed us your code, but you didn't ask us a question or any explain any issue you might be having.

Comment: @ADyson I managed to figure it out all by myself! Still, thanks for your reply!